# Failed to generate makefiles (intel-qs)

Tags: c++, cmake, intel

https://github.com/iqusoft/intel-qs/issues/32#issue-708056939

I downloaded the relevant package and ran the instructions as shown in the document until I got an error at this step.
CXX=mpiicpc cmake -DIqsMPI=ON -DIqsUtest=ON ..

Then it reported an error

```
root@vm:~/intel-qs/build# CXX=mpiicpc cmake -DIqsMPI=ON -DIqsUtest=ON ..

-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpiicpc
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpiicpc -- broken
CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.12.2/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpiicpc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /root/intel-qs/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_3abc4/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abc4.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abc4.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/root/intel-qs/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abc4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpiicpc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abc4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /root/intel-qs/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpiicpc: 1: eval: icpc: not found
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abc4.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abc4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3abc4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 127
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/intel-qs/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_3abc4/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_3abc4/fast] Error 2
    
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/intel-qs/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/intel-qs/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

If anyone knows how to do it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have the error `icpc: not found`. Is `icpc` compiler installed on your machine and is this compiler available via `PATH`?

Comment: I installed mpiicpc, and after I specified mpiicpc in cmake command, another error occurred. CMake Error: The source directory "/root/intel-qs/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Have you tried to google for that new error message? It tells that you are specifying wrong source directory in `cmake` invocation.

Comment: cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpiicpc -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DIqsMPI=ON -DIqsUtest=ON .. (This is the command I ran, and I added .. at the end, alright, now I have reported the first error before)

Comment: So, returning to the questions in my comment, do you have `icpc` compiler installed and whether it is available in `PATH`? What if you just type `icpc` in the command line?

Comment: I typed icpc and it shows that there is no such command. I currently have this installed, https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/parallel-studio-xe/choose-download/free-trial-cluster-linux.html , it should contain Intel® C++ Compiler, so I need to install icpc separately now? How to install it?